How to use the remote repository’s reference advertisement list in git2
In Rust's git2 library, there is a list function that returns a remote repositories reference advertisement list.
The resulting RemoteHead structs can return a name, oid, and loid, but how are these usable to determine what is point to by a reference? For example, are they all references to trees,blobs, commits? How do I then retrieve anything associated with those references?
Code snippet example to where I am stuck:
    let repo = Repository::open(".")?;
    // Value passed to function: url (&String)
    let remote = url;
    let mut remote = repo
        .find_remote(remote)
        .or_else(|_| repo.remote_anonymous(remote))?;

    // Connect to the remote and call the printing function for each of the
    // remote references.
    let connection = remote.connect_auth(Direction::Fetch, None, None)?;

    let mut retrieved_tags: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    // Get the list of references on the remote and print out their name and oid
    for head in connection.list()?.iter() {
        println!("{}\t{}", head.oid(), head.name());
        if head.name().starts_with("refs/tags/") {
            retrieved_tags.push(head.name().to_string());
        }
    }

    // WHAT GOES HERE TO PULL DATA FROM REFERENCES, OR QUERY WHAT THEY ARE? 

I've been looking into fetchspecs since I'm not really familiar with git internals, but I can't find the exact method in git2 to work, or any methods that will give me more information on what the reference points to.

Native git serves as metadata basically just reference names and id's, you'll have to fetch the reference to see exactly what it looks like up close. I don't see where libgit2 has any notion of filtering, if it's really missing (and libgit2 is good at what it does but it isn't all of Git) you'll get at least one full snapshot for a commit ref.
